# Create Custom UIView with Custom WebView and UISearchContoller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview, uisearchcontroller

I'm working on an iOS app and I created an `UIViewController` where I put my components and it works fine .
Now I'm trying to create a Custom `UIView` and to put my `WebView` and my `SearchController` into . I spent a lot of time without success .

Here is my `.m` file and I hope some one can help me with :

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"


#define widthtScreen  [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
#define heightScreen  [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height


@interface HomeViewController () <UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate,UIBarPositioningDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,MapWebViewDelegate>

@property(strong,nonatomic) MapWebView *webView;

@property (nonatomic) UIButton  *btnGeolocate;


@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController{
    NSMutableArray *placesList;
    BOOL isSearching;
}



-(void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    self.webView = [[MapWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -100, widthtScreen, heightScreen+100)];
    self.webView.mapWebViewDelegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    placesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self initializeSearchController];
    mainDelegate.webView = self.webView;


    self.btnGeolocate = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-75,550,60,60)];
    self.btnGeolocate.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [self.btnGeolocate setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"geo.png"]
                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnGeolocate addTarget:self action:@selector(btnGeolocatePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.btnGeolocate];

    mainDelegate.btnZoomIn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-80,620,30,30)];
    mainDelegate.btnZoomIn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [mainDelegate.btnZoomIn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [mainDelegate.btnZoomIn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnZoomInPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    mainDelegate.btnZoomIn.tag=1;
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"];
    [mainDelegate.btnZoomIn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:mainDelegate.btnZoomIn];

    mainDelegate.btnZoomOut = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-40,620,30,30)];
    mainDelegate.btnZoomOut.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [mainDelegate.btnZoomOut setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [mainDelegate.btnZoomOut addTarget:self action:@selector(btnZoomOutPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    mainDelegate.btnZoomOut.tag=1;
    UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"minus.png"];
    [mainDelegate.btnZoomOut setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:mainDelegate.btnZoomOut];
}

- (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayLeftMenu
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayRightMenu
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"number :%lu",(unsigned long)[placesList count]);
    return [placesList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    SuggestResultObject *sro = [SuggestResultObject new];
    sro = [placesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = sro.textPlace;
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =nil;
    return true;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = mainDelegate.leftBarButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = mainDelegate.rightBarButtonItem;
    SuggestResultObject *sro = [SuggestResultObject new];
    sro = [placesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.searchController.active = false;
    NSString *function = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"MobileManager.getInstance().moveToLocation(\"%@\",\"%@\")", sro.latPlace,sro.lonPlace];
    [_webView evaluateJavaScript:function completionHandler:nil];
}



- (void)jsRun:(NSString *) searchText {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString *function = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"MobileManager.getInstance().setSuggest(\"%@\")", searchText];
        [_webView evaluateJavaScript:function completionHandler:nil];
    });
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearching = YES;
}

- (void)initializeSearchController {
    UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;
    self.searchController.accessibilityElementsHidden= true;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true;
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = mainDelegate.leftBarButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = mainDelegate.rightBarButtonItem;
    NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    [placesList removeAllObjects];
}


-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    [placesList removeAllObjects];
    if([searchController.searchBar.text length] != 0) {
        isSearching = YES;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
        [self jsRun:searchController.searchBar.text];
    }
    else {
        isSearching = NO;
        [((UITableViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController).tableView reloadData];
    }
}

-(void) btnGeolocatePressed : (id) sender{
}

-(void) btnZoomInPressed : (id) sender{
    [_webView evaluateJavaScript:@"MobileManager.getInstance().zoomIn();" completionHandler:nil];
}

-(void) btnZoomOutPressed : (id) sender{
    [_webView evaluateJavaScript:@"MobileManager.getInstance().zoomOut();" completionHandler:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)searchResult:(NSArray*)dataArray{
    SuggestResultObject *sro = [SuggestResultObject new];
    sro.textPlace = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
    sro.lonPlace = [dataArray objectAtIndex:1];
    sro.latPlace = [dataArray objectAtIndex:2];
    [placesList addObject:sro];
    [((UITableViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController).tableView reloadData];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
@end
```

Comment: Hi OP, It would help if you actually told us what the problem was instead of: "Here is my code, help".

Comment: the problem is that i'm trying to put the custom webview with the uisearchcontroller into a custom uiview then call it in uiviewcontroller but I couldn't do that because in the view i couldn't use a navigationcontroller and even when i created it manually it doesn't work

Comment: @OP; You want a UIWebView and UISearchController embedded into a UIViewController which is embedded in a NavigationController? OR do you want a UIWebView and UISearchController embedded in a NavigationController which is embedded in a UIView?

Comment: I want a UIWebView and UISearchController embedded into UIView

Comment: And when I called into UIViewController it should not have problems with the navigation controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screenshots (Not sure how to scale images on stackoverflow.. OSX takes images in Retina format and they're fairly large! Sorry in advance!):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE0Zs.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VX8v.png

> How it works? Create a `UIView` and two sub-views: `UITableView` and
>   `UIWebView`. Constrain them properly.
>
> Create the `UISearchController` with a `nil` SearchResultsController
>   as the parameter to the `init` method.
>
> This lets the search controller know that the results will be
>   displayed in the current controller/view.
>
> Next we setup the delegates for the `UISearchController` and create
>   the function for filtering.
>
> Now that we have the view created, we need a `UIViewController` to
>   test it. We can either add the search bar to the tableView header OR
>   to the NavigationController if there is one..
>
> Below, I have chosen to add it to the `UINavigationController` and I
>   told the `UISearchController` to NOT HIDE the navigation bar on
>   presentation.
>
> That way, the results are displayed in the current view without hiding
>   the navigation bar.
>
> You can then use the webview which is hidden and offscreen to do
>   whatever javascript searches you are using it for..
>
> However, a better idea would be to use `JSContext` to execute
>   Javascript instead of a `UIWebView`. The advantage of the `UIWebView`
>   is that you can parse HTML and modify DOM which the `JSContext`
>   doesn't allow.
>
> Anyway..
>
> Here is the code I wrote for a `UIView` that contains a
>   `UISearchController` and a `UIWebView`.. and then to add it to a
>   `UIViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

```
//
//  SearchView.h
//  StackOverflow
//
//  Created by Brandon T on 2016-06-26.
//  Copyright © 2016 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SearchView;

@protocol SearchViewDelegate <UISearchBarDelegate>
- (void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(SearchView *)searchView tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@interface SearchView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SearchViewDelegate> delegate;
- (UISearchBar *)getSearchBar;
- (UIWebView *)getWebView;
@end


//
//  SearchView.m
//  StackOverflow
//
//  Created by Brandon T on 2016-06-26.
//  Copyright © 2016 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SearchView.h"

#define kTableViewCellIdentifier @"kTableViewCellIdentifier"

@interface SearchView() <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataSource;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *searchResults;
@end

@implementation SearchView

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        [self setupData];
        [self initControls];
        [self themeControls];
        [self registerCells];
        [self doLayout];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UISearchBar *)getSearchBar {
    return _searchController.searchBar;
}

- (UIWebView *)getWebView {
    return _webView;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id<SearchViewDelegate>)delegate {
    _delegate = delegate;
    _searchController.searchBar.delegate = delegate;
}

- (void)setupData {
    //Begin fake data

    _dataSource = @[@"Cat", @"Dog", @"Bird", @"Parrot", @"Rabbit", @"Racoon", @"Rat", @"Hamster", @"Pig", @"Cow"];

    //End fake data


    _searchResults = [_dataSource copy];
}

- (void)initControls {
    _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
}

- (void)themeControls {
    [_webView setHidden:YES];

    [_tableView setDelegate:self];
    [_tableView setDataSource:self];

    _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
    _searchController.definesPresentationContext = true;
    _searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;
}

- (void)registerCells {
    [_tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:kTableViewCellIdentifier];
}

- (void)doLayout {
    [self addSubview:_webView];
    [self addSubview:_tableView];

    NSDictionary *views = @{@"webView":_webView, @"tableView": _tableView};
    NSMutableArray *constraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [constraints addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-(%d)-[webView]-(%d)-|", 0, 0]];
    [constraints addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-(%d)-[tableView]-(%d)-|", 0, 0]];

    [constraints addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-(%d)-[webView(%d)]-(%d)-[tableView]-(%d)-|", -100, 100, 0, 0]];

    for (NSString *constraint in constraints) {
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:constraint options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    }

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _searchController.active && _searchController.searchBar.text.length > 0 ? [_searchResults count] : [_dataSource count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 50;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTableViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (_searchController.active && _searchController.searchBar.text.length > 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = _searchResults[indexPath.row];
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = _dataSource[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectRowAtIndexPath:tableView:indexPath:)]) {
        [self.delegate didSelectRowAtIndexPath:self tableView:tableView indexPath:indexPath];
    }
}


- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    [self filterResults:searchController.searchBar.text scope:nil];
}

- (void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope {
    _searchResults = [_dataSource filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {

        NSString *object = [evaluatedObject uppercaseString];
        return [object rangeOfString:[searchText uppercaseString]].location != NSNotFound;
    }]];

    [_tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Then I tested it with the below `UIViewController` which is embedded in a `UINavigationController`..

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  StackOverflow
//
//  Created by Brandon T on 2016-06-26.
//  Copyright © 2016 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SearchView.h"


@interface ViewController ()<SearchViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) SearchView *searchView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initControls];
    [self themeControls];
    [self doLayout];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


- (void)initControls {
    _searchView = [[SearchView alloc] init];
}

- (void)themeControls {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [_searchView getSearchBar];

    [_searchView setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)doLayout {
    [self.view addSubview:_searchView];

    NSDictionary *views = @{@"searchView":_searchView};
    NSMutableArray *constraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [constraints addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-%d-[searchView]-%d-|", 0, 0]];
    [constraints addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-%d-[searchView]-%d-|", 0, 0]];

    for (NSString *constraint in constraints) {
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:constraint options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    }

    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    }
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = nil;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil;
}

- (void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(SearchView *)searchView tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [[searchView getWebView] stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"SomeJavascriptHere"];

}
@end
```

Comment: Big thanks man 
- (UISearchBar *)getSearchBar {
    return _searchController.searchBar;
}
this is the function that is missed in my code

Comment: After some test when I click on the search bar and type . it disappear

Comment: The code I posted does not hide the search bar because: `_searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;` and the search bar is in the navigation bar.

Comment: yes I did the same and i got this when i type for search 
http://imgur.com/dHSlE06

Comment: it's actually the UITableView which hide the Navigation Bar

Comment: Try using `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` That way, the `tableView` will be UNDER the navigation bar.

Comment: You have something else above it, hiding it. I don't know because I can't see the code.

Comment: Ok I will try to fix it. One more Question , I used this delegate on my UIViewController : - (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =nil;
    return true;
}
How can I call the navigation buttons on the view ?

Comment: What do you mean: "How can I call the navigation buttons on the view"? I don't understand that question. You are destroying both navigation buttons by setting them to nil.

Comment: Yes I want to set the navigation buttons to nil when I click on the search bar . It works when my code was on the UIViewController but now it's on the UIView so how can I destroy them?

Comment: You can destroy them in the view controller that owns the search bar. Add a delegate from the search bar to the view to let you know when it has started editing.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I added the delegate to the view and I didn't know how to call the navigation item

Comment: Updated the answer to include a delegate. Now you can set the delegate in your view controller and it will get notified of any events on the search bar. You can add other functions to the delegate as well.

Comment: I fixed the problem of the tableview now it works fine 
http://imgur.com/Kk9C9ta I added this : self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

Comment: One more thing, when I click on the tableview ,the navigation buttons should appear . I tried to do the same as the delegate for the search bar it works but i have to inject javascript inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath to the webview Any suggestions ?!

Comment: Do it via the delegate and call the JavaScript method on the webview passed in through the deleGate.

Comment: Updated the code. I've added a delegate to show how to get the tableview information AND call javascript on the embedded web-view.